ROSCORE RLException: ERROR: could not contact master
I have installed ROS noetic in ubuntu 20.04 and when I try to run roscore I always have following fault.
I have source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh and export | grep ROS result shows good.
declare -x ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=""
declare -x ROS_DISTRO="noetic"
declare -x ROS_ETC_DIR="/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros"
declare -x ROS_MASTER_URI="http://localhost:11311"
declare -x ROS_PACKAGE_PATH="/opt/ros/noetic/share"
declare -x ROS_PYTHON_VERSION="3"
declare -x ROS_ROOT="/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros"
declare -x ROS_VERSION="1"
I have checked /etc/hosts and also change the combination of ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME to my ip address and hostname, but result is the same, ping IP and hostname shows fine with delay<0.03ms, follow ROS network check guideline, netcat -l 11311 shows fine and I think network should be okay.
could you pls help me about that? any suggestion would be appreciate.


On this site, please do not post images of text. Instead, copy/paste the actual text and format it.

What did you set your ROS_HOSTNAME environment variable to?

I have set ROS_HOSTNAME to "localhost" or my computer name "hu-fengjian-sha", and these two can be reachable by ping command and netcat. and I can see they are also in /etc/hosts, but none of them works.

You should be sourcing setup.bash, not setup.sh. In a new terminal window, try these commands:
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost
roscore -p 11311


thank you for your kindly help, but the result is still the same.  it shows could not RLException: ERROR: could not contact master [http://localhost:11311/]

btw I am using zsh shell now and I cannot sourcing setup.bash directly, then I switch to bash and then sourcing setup.bash and it works.  but result is the same with the commands
